# Remove specific iterations from foreach loop PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I have below loop and I want to exclude records if type == 'news' and unread count is 0
I have tried unset option but didn't works for me.

```
                $f = new stdClass();
                $f->course_id = $forum->course;
                $f->type = $forum->type;
                 $f->unread = $unread;
                 $forum->type = $forum->type == 'news' ? 'announcements' : 'forums';
                 //need fix here 
                 if($forum->type =='news' && $unread ==0){
                    unset($f);}
                $results[$forum->type][] = $f;
```

Output :

```
  data: {
    announcements : [{}]
   //fix should apply here. if type is news and unread =0 it shouldn show
    newa: [{}]
    }
```

Comment: There is no loop here. Please edit your question with sample data, the actual code you're using, and expected output.

Comment: _“I have tried unset option but didn't works for me”_ - it makes no sense whatsoever, that you unset a variable in one line, and then try to append that same variable to an array one line later. _What_ variable? You just unset it – killed it, wiped it from existence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the logic around to say only store ones which either aren't news or have been read

```
if($forum->type !='news' || $unread != 0){
    $results[$forum->type][] = $f;
}
```

(although having an `unread` flag can be a bit confusing and may be worth changing the logic to have a flag called `read` instead)

Comment: This didn't work. since it has || (OR) it will show both 0 records as well. This array filtering for form types 'news' and 'announcmeents' I want to hide items if the forum type is news and unread == 0 only.

Comment: If `$forum->type !='news'` it will ignore `$unread != 0` as it knows the answer to the `||` will be true.